# Create a many-to-many constraint or cross reference table that references one table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite, many-to-many, data-modeling

I have a situation where I would I have a many-to-many relationship on a single table. This is just a quick example of one example. Right now it is just a raw csv dump into a table. But I would like to add a cross reference table or a constraint so that when I can query a vendor. For brevity, I just show the two ID's.

How would I go about adding that relationship to the below example? I am using SQLlite at the moment but I plan on translating it to either MS server or Postgres for the final tables.

```
 global_duns   vendor_duns
      9581091  53506312
      9581091  961273620
     79735371  53506312
     79735371  79735371
     79735371  135962137
```

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS company;

PRAGMA foreign_keys=off;

CREATE TABLE company
(
    CompanyId  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    global_duns_number  INTEGER REFERENCES data(global_duns_number),
    vendor_duns INTEGER REFERENCES data(vendor_duns),

    CONSTRAINT unique_global UNIQUE (global_duns_number),
    CONSTRAINT unique_dun UNIQUE (vendor_duns),
    CONSTRAINT unique_vendor UNIQUE (global_duns_number, vendor_duns),
    CONSTRAINT unique_vendor_reverse UNIQUE (vendor_duns, global_duns_number)
);

INSERT INTO company (global_duns_number, vendor_duns)
SELECT DISTINCT global_duns_number, vendor_duns 
FROM data;

PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
```

Where data is a raw csv import.

Comment: Do you have any idea of how the expected output look like?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I would like to sum contract values. For example if each row of the above example had 1 million in contract value it would return 5 million.

Comment: Sorry i didn't ask my question clearly. Can you say the provide the output for the sample date in your question?

Comment: You have told us what you have, but we still do not understand what you want. Show the desired output.

Comment: I guess in the above table, there would be another column called companyID, the 5 global and the 5 vendor would have the same companyID. That way I could join a companyID on to a table with total contract amounts and group by the companyID to get aggregrate contranct amounts.